# Form display in new page

Tags: database, forms

i am new to wordpress i am trying to create a new table and save the form data into it. I have the following code. I created a child theme.
Functions.php:

```
function elh_insert_into_db() {

    global $wpdb;
    // creates my_table in database if not exists
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "my_table"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
        `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` text NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`id`)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    // starts output buffering
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="#v_form" method="post" id="v_form">
        <label for="visitor_name"><h3>Hello there! What is your name?</h3></label>
        <input type="text" name="visitor_name" id="visitor_name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    // does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] != "" ) {
        $table = $wpdb->prefix."my_table";
        $name = strip_tags($_POST["visitor_name"], "");
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'name' => $name
            )
        );
        $html = "<p>Your name <strong>$name</strong> was successfully recorded. Thanks!!</p>";
    }
    // if the form is submitted but the name is empty
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["visitor_name"] == "" )
        $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
    // outputs everything
    return $html;

}
// adds a shortcode you can use: [insert-into-db]
add_shortcode('elh-db-insert', 'elh_insert_into_db');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_scripts' );
function my_child_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '../twentyseventeen/style.css' );
}
?>
```

How do i see this form. All i see when i activate this theme is the parent theme. How do i display this form and create the table? And after saving how do i display the data into the template? Can someone help me with it? I want to understand when functions.php file runs.

Comment: You should try using the shortcode. Login to the Dashboard and open an existing page for editing. In the editor window paste the following shortcode [insert-into-db]. Save the page and then view your changes.

Comment: When i add [elh-db-insert] as content its just printing it out. Its not calling the function.

Comment: Its Working thanks. I had a problem with the style.css file so it was not loading. Should i keep this function in Functions.php or can i create a different php file and call it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new page and put [elh-db-insert] as content.

If you want to use [insert-into-db] as your shorcode, you should change

> add_shortcode('elh-db-insert', 'elh_insert_into_db');

to

> add_shortcode('insert-into-db', 'elh_insert_into_db');

Comment: When i add [elh-db-insert] as content its just printing it out. Its not calling the function.

Comment: Its Working thanks. I had a problem with the style.css file so it was not loading. Should i keep this function in Functions.php or can i create a different php file and call it from there?